# SQL Server Join with a table with composite key

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have four tables I need to join in the following query attemp:

```
SELECT PROJECT.PROJECT_ID
     , PROJECT_STATUS.PRO_STATUS_NAME
     , PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME
     , SKILL.SKILL_NAME
FROM PROJECT_STATUS
INNER JOIN PROJECT    ON PROJECT_STATUS.PRO_STATUS_ID = PROJECT.PRO_STATUS_ID
INNER JOIN PRO_SKILL  ON SKILL.SKILL_ID = PRO_SKILL.SKILL_ID 
                     AND PRO_SKILL.PROJECT_ID = PROJECT.PROJECT_ID;
```

Unfortunately the PRO_SKILL table uses a composite key so I keep getting the following error when trying to run the query:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The multi-part identifier
>   "SKILL.SKILL_ID" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line
>   1 The multi-part identifier "SKILL.SKILL_NAME" could not be bound.

Is there a way to join properly with a table that uses a composite key?

PRO_SKILL HAS A COMPOSITE KEY MADE OF:
PROJECT_ID AND SKILL_ID

SKILL ONLY HAS A REGULAR PK MADE OF SKILL_ID

Thank you for your help in advance!.

Comment: where is your SKILL join. i don't see that in your query.

Comment: @sqlhdv I have made the following changes to the query to address your suggestion (thanks!)  SELECT PROJECT.PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_STATUS.PRO_STATUS_NAME, PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME, SKILL.SKILL_NAME
FROM PROJECT_STATUS
INNER JOIN PROJECT
ON PROJECT_STATUS.PRO_STATUS_ID = PROJECT.PRO_STATUS_ID
INNER JOIN SKILL
ON SKILL.SKILL_ID = PRO_SKILL.SKILL_ID
INNER JOIN PRO_SKILL
ON PRO_SKILL.PROJECT_ID = PROJECT.PROJECT_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed out the Skills table , Try this....

```
SELECT PROJECT.PROJECT_ID
     , PROJECT_STATUS.PRO_STATUS_NAME
     , PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME
     , SKILL.SKILL_NAME
FROM PROJECT_STATUS
INNER JOIN PROJECT    ON PROJECT_STATUS.PRO_STATUS_ID = PROJECT.PRO_STATUS_ID
INNER JOIN PRO_SKILL  ON PRO_SKILL.PROJECT_ID = PROJECT.PROJECT_ID
INNER JOIN SKILL      ON SKILL.SKILL_ID = PRO_SKILL.SKILL_ID
```